# JSF - <h:outputText> making some of words Bold

Tags: java, jsf, tags

How can we go about making some of the words in a sentence appear in BOLD

for example -  I'm trying to put one of the words of a sentence in BOLD i.e.

sentence is "please select the amount"

amount should be in BOLD, and now, when I use

```
message = "please select the <b>amount </b>"
```

This doesn't work. It simply shows

```
please select the <b>amount </b>.
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 25):

Setting the escape attribute to false allows you to insert html tags

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="please select the <b>amount</b>"/>
```

Comment: And keep XSS risks in mind. Never do this for user-controlled input.

Comment: It doesnt work under the tooltip in primefaces. for example, <p:tooltip for=".."><h:outputText escape="false" value="please select the <b>amount</b>"/></p:tooltip>.

Comment: I replaced each < with &lt; and > with &gt; and the problem dissappered however I didnt see the html code on web page

Comment: I have solved the problem.It is worked so far. I put it in textarea.Here is my code -> <p:tooltip  for="@previous">
<div style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;">HTML Code - Sample</div><textarea disabled="disabled" style="border: none; background-color: white;" cols="40" rows="4">&lt;p&gt;The content&lt;/p&gt;</textarea></p:tooltip>

Comment: Thanks to  Günay Gültekin comment, the solution becomes:

 <h:outputText escape="false" value="please select the &lt;strong&gt;amount&lt;/strong&gt;"/>

Comment: The key is with scape="false" thanks!