# How can i show text with html tag in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I get a String from `< p:editor>` like this : `< b>This is bold text< /b>`.
I want to show `<b>This is bold text</b>` in xhtml page. What tag can i use to do that ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<strike>Use an outputText with `escape="true"`:</strike>

```
<h:outputText escape="true" value="<b>This is bold</b>"/>
```

As stated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859):

> ...Facelets implicitly wraps **inline** [emphasis added] content in a component as represented by `<h:outputText>`

So, if you don't use an `outputText` tag with the `escape` attribute set to `true` Facelets will add one for you <strike>which will escape the html tags.</strike>

**Edit:** I am completely wrong about the `escape` attribute.  Please forgive my ignorance as I am still learning as well.  According to the documentation the `escape` attribute:

> Flag indicating that characters that are sensitive in HTML and XML markup must be escaped. This flag is set to "true" by default.

Please see the answer to [this OS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467750/jsf-houtputtext-making-some-of-words-bold/2467886#2467886) for a correct example.