# How to display raw HTML tags in p:column?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a user note field in the DB and it can contain new lines.  I have a getter in my entity object which replaces all the `\n` characters coming from the DB with `<br/>`.  It goes into a `p:dataTable`.  But when I display the value using `p:column`, it changes the HTML tags so they are shown and not used as directives to format data display:

```
<p:column width="500" style="word-wrap: break-word">
    <f:facet name="header">User Note</f:facet>
    #{entity.userNoteDisplay}
</p:column>
```

So if the userNote value in the entity object is:

```
This is 
user note
```

then `getUserNoteDisplay` returns `This is<br/>user note`.

However, the HTML table cell shows exactly `This is<br/>user note`, displaying the `<br/>`.

How can I make it so that it interprets and not literally shows HTML tags?

RELATED:  [How can i show text with html tag in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858521/how-can-i-show-text-with-html-tag-in-primefaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF escaping worked:

```
<p:column width="500" style="word-wrap: break-word">
    <f:facet name="header">User Note</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value ="#{entity.userNoteDisplay}" escape="false"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: If you disabled escaping I hope you filter the user input because interesting things might happen if someone type something like `<script>alert('xss')</script>` .

Comment: As is all mentioned in the duplicate. Wonder why people don't find these duplicates. Questions marked duplicate are mostly posted by first askers or people that ask lots of basic questions